# Redirect dirty urls to a clean url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, redirect, friendly-url

Alright so I have done the process of cleaning up my urls and everything is going good I put the following in my htaccess.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ /l/index.php?mp3=$1&img=http://www.dailynewsounds.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/tinashe-5535799554a1b-3.jpg&g=R\%26amp\%3BB&p=8\%20hours\%20ago&s=+Energy&a=Tinashe+Ft.+Juicy+J+ [L]
```

And this works to change my urls but we have our nasty urls directing to the pages.

```
http://dl.example.com/l/index.php?mp3=oo8aey7qw3n9&img=http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/stuey-rock-ft-sy-ari-da-kid-569e83c69cf5e.jpeg&g=R%26amp%3BB&p=10%20hours%20ago&s=+Me+And+You&a=Stuey+Rock+Ft.+Sy+Ari+Da+Kid+
```

How can I make it so that I can check my url to see if it contains `index.php` and if it does redirect it to the new page?

Comment: the new page would be?

Comment: @hjpotter92 example.com/193812412.html

Comment: So, basically the value passed for `mp3` parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /l/index\.php\?\S*mp3=\S* [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} \bmp3=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1.html? [R=301,L]
```

If you're using Apache 2.4.x, then replace the `L]` with `L,QSD]`.

Comment: it returns a url when I use this `http://dl.example.com/oo8aey7qw3n9.html?mp3=oo8aey7qw3n9&img=http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/stuey-rock-ft-sy-ari-da-kid-569e83c69cf5e.jpeg&g=R%26amp%3BB&p=10%20hours%20ago&s=+Me+And+You&a=Stuey+Rock+Ft.+Sy+Ari+Da+Kid`